# ask facebook to return posts filtered by type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get all the posts from an user based on its type (e.g. `link` or `status`) and I haven't found anything in the docs. I tried apply a filter like

```
me/posts?fields=status_type,type{link},link,message,created_time
```

but the answer is "message": "Subfields are not supported by type". Is there a way I can filter it in Facebook or should I do it on my side?

Comment: where in the docs did you find that filter option? i´ve never seen that one before.

Comment: sorry, wrong copy/paste. updated

Comment: No, the API doesn’t allow for that kind of filtering.